# How to highlight a gridx row without selecting it in Dojo (Without checking the checkbox)

Tags: dojo, row, highlight, gridx

I am trying in my code to force the grid to have a highlighted row, I know there is no property to do this. (There's only a **select** one) How can I do a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If 'rowId' is the index of row to be highlighted, then

```
grid.row(rowId).node().style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

If you already overridden styles for cell, then applying just to row wont have any effect. Then you have to iterate over cells within row and highlight the cells

```
cellNode.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```